# D3: How to validate data during data binding?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to render a gantt chart, where I am binding my data in d3 and rendering circle in both end. My data is somewhat similar to this structure:

```
function Event(start, end) {
    this.startTime = start;
    this.endTime = end;
}
```

I bind my data as usual:

```
myplot.selectAll(".EventStart")
       .data(EventList).enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("class", "EventStart")
       .attr("cx", function (d) { return scaleX(d.startTime)})
       .attr("cy", function (d) { return eventRenderingHeight })
       .attr("r", 5)
       .style("fill", "white");

myplot.selectAll(".EventEnd")
       .data(EventList).enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("class", "EventEnd")
       .attr("cx", function (d) { return scaleX(d.endTime)})
       .attr("cy", function (d) { return eventRenderingHeight })
       .attr("r", 5)
       .style("fill", "white");
```

Now, this will render two white circle at teh begining and end of my events.
But I want to omit rendering the 2nd circle if startTime and EndTime is same.
How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Filter the data before passing it to D3.

Comment: So I guess there is no way to incorporate data checking/filtering after data binding?

Comment: You can also filter D3 selections, but you can achieve the same thing by filtering the data before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either filter the `dataList` before binding

```
myplot.selectAll(".EventEnd")
           .data(EventList.filter(function(d){ return d.startTime!=d.endTime }))
           .enter()
           .append("circle")           
           .attr("class", "EventEnd")
           .attr("cx", function (d) { return scaleX(d.endTime)})
           .attr("cy", function (d) { return eventRenderingHeight })
           .attr("r", 5)
           .style("fill", "white");
```

OR

Filter as shown below.

```
myplot.selectAll(".EventEnd")
       .data(EventList)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .filter(function(d) { return d.startTime!=d.endTime })
       .attr("class", "EventEnd")
       .attr("cx", function (d) { return scaleX(d.endTime)})
       .attr("cy", function (d) { return eventRenderingHeight })
       .attr("r", 5)
       .style("fill", "white");
```